x position of a figure
I am currently writing a report, and I am using Latex. Since it is a report in the physics field, I have many figures to include in this. There is a figure I made by myself, and without entering into too many details, imagine a tube with text on the right side explaining what each element is. Since I made this simple figure using PowerPoint, and group every element in there, the "center" of the image is somewhere between the tube and the text. So when using the \centering command in LaTeX, it centers the figure around that point. However, I'd like to center it on the middle axis of the tube. Is there a command to tune the x position of a figure? Or something to add space on the left side (hence displacing the figure to the right)?
Thanks in advance!
EDIT: Here is the code I use for my figure(s):
\begin{figure}[ht]\renewcommand{\thefigure{2.1.\arabic{figure}}
\smallskip
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Images/Schema_Dilu.png}
\caption{\small{...}}
\label{fig:2.1.2}
\end{figure}

I figured using "\advance\leftskip6.5cm" works, but is there any other solution?

Welcome to TeX.SE.  We're probably going to need more details.  How are you including the PowerPoint figure in your tex file?  Did you export a jpg from PPT, and \includegraphics it into tex?  (By the way, you can remove the "overleaf" tag with your next edit - it's not relevant to how to place a figure.)

I hope I am replying to you. I edited my message to include the code I am using as well as removing the tag.

Note that \small does not take an argument. It acts like a switch rather. So, you might want to remove the curly braces there. And you probably want to remove the unmatched open curly brace before \thefigure.

You did not provide a minimal working example (MWE), but you can use \hspace*{1cm} before and/or after \includegraphics to add horizontal space if needed, but it might be better to create the picture in a way that it is centered in the first place. You could also trim the image. It depends on the concrete use case ...

Well, removing the curly braces of \small does indeed work, but I am a bit lazy to do that for all of my figures, so I'll leave it for now, but I will be sure to not include it in my next reports. For some reason, the curly brace was removed after \thefigure in my message, but it is there in my code. And removing it somehow breaks my figure. I don't have enough knowledge of LaTeX.
I also tried the \hspace*{1cm} and it seems to be working with 6.5cm. I'll be using it. As for trimming, my image is already trimmed to the maximum, I can't trim it further.
